# This site versus [wordpress] on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, scope

Which questions belong on WordPress Answers but not on SO? Which questions belong on [SO with a [wordpress] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) but not on WordPress Answers? How can we keep the experts here instead of on Stack Overflow?

[The definition of this site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1500?phase=definition) is:

> Beta Q&A site for wordpress developers and administrators. If you write plugins or themes, or administer your own WordPress site then this is the site for you.

I can see many questions on [the WordPress.org support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/) that are not suited for Stack Overflow. Since our definition also includes people administrating but not developing sites, I think we are supposed to welcome questions about plugins and themes by people that don't know PHP (very well)?

But I can also imagine that more expert users (which we need here) will say "keep the silly theme questions on WordPress Answers, I'll only look for difficult coding questions on Stack Overflow". How can we prevent this, [without diluting the value of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52869/will-these-proposals-have-a-potential-to-dilute-what-stack-overflow-has-going)?

Answer (score 16):

I think **all** questions regarding WordPress belong here, as long as they are truly WP dependent and not just PHP stuff. 
So, ideally, I think that [wordpress] tag on SO should start to disappear, because there is now this site which is more suited.

Also, I've asked some questions about WP before on SO and I had little success in getting answers, at least as fast as other disciplines.

Comment: Agreed. The same goes for webmasters.

Comment: I am apparently not the only one looking for WordPress help from SO and not finding it.

Comment: This site really gathers a good share of WP regulars, so to create more identification with the topic here. So it's an add.

Comment: Completely agreed.

Answer (score 10):

Personally I've love to see everything on StackOverflow related to WordPress move here (just my preference.) After all, if you ask a net admin question on StackOverflow you are directed to ServerFault; why not the same here?

Frankly would also love to see all the existing WordPress content on SO migrated here, but that would require the SE guys to agree and move it over, me thinks.

Comment: I'm of the same mind, it makes sense to me to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If someone tags a question with [wordpress] on SO, maybe a modal dialogue could show up and ask the user if they want to post their question on this site instead?  Let the user decide.

Comment: If this can be implemented easily it might just do the trick. Any volunteers to try and arrange this with the overlords?

Comment: @dewald see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths/

Comment: I don't see wordpress.stackexchange in the list of sites available for migration from SO in the off-topic options

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that Wordpress tag in SO should dissapear. But new questions specifically to wordpress development could be migrated here.

Comment: I mean that from now on all questions will probably be posted here, so SO will have less and less questions on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Existing questions on StackOverflow can probably stay where they are. Since this new site is purported to be for WP developers AND users, all new WP-related questions should be posted (or moved) here.

Comment: OK, but moving questions to other Stack Exchange sites will probably not be possible until this site is out of beta, and the only way to get out of beta is to be successful. How do we bridge that gap?

Comment: @Jan Fabry That's true, I had forgotten that detail. If/when this site matures, the issue should diminish. Until then, the community will guide this site's growth. Give it time.