# Should we actively promote this site on [wordpress] questions on SO?

Tags: discussion, promotion

At least as long as this site is in beta, we should not expect [a way to move questions from Stack Overflow to this site](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/this-site-versus-wordpress-on-stack-overflow/11#11). Should we actively monitor [the `[wordpress]` tag on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wordpress) and place a comment *"Please re-ask your question on the more specific WordPress Stack Exchange site"* on each question? Or only on (older) [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/wordpress)? I have seen some comments like it, but I don't know whether this is a co-ordinated action?

Also, when I look at [the people most active in the `[wordpress]` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wordpress/stats), I see some names that I recognize from here, but also others that seem not to have discovered this site yet. How could we get them to answer questions here?

Comment: *@Jan Fabry* - One question I have is *"Do StackExchange have an issue with use trying to draw users and traffic from StackOverflow, or are they okay with us promoting this site over there?"*  If they are okay, I say by all means we should let everyone at SO who posts on [wordpress] know about WA.

Answer (score 5):

Getting questions migrated here will be an essential way to grow the site. However, [migration paths will be limited to a few per site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths/), and WordPress is probably too small to get a place on Stack Overflow. For that reason [I created a feature request to let the migration paths depend on the question tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags). This way, a question tagged `[wordpress]` would get a migration path to this site, but other questions would not see it. Please vote for it if you think it deserves attention from the powers that be!

Comment: It **absolutely makes sense** to have the question tags define the migration path. Guys, if you have a few free seconds go over and up-vote @Jan's SO post, please: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags

Comment: +1, done.. i scored some rep making/linking an account to, bonus!... :)

Answer (score 4):

I'll usually suggest that people come to this site as an additional resource, but I also answer the question there as well.

From an end user perspective, being endlessly replied to with "You should have asked that question over here instead" is frustrating and a massive waste of time.  If I've already asked the question once, I'd like you to just answer it rather than criticizing the fact that I didn't know about a little used (look at our use rate as opposed to SO) specialized beta site.

When I first started on SO, I was bounced back and forth from so many different sites that I eventually stopped using my account all together.  It takes 3 seconds to say "ask somewhere else" ... it takes just a few seconds longer to actually ask the question or provide *an actual link* to that other site's answer.

Answer (score 1):

For newer questions, it's reasonable to suggest they be reposted on the WordPress site. For existing questions, I'd leave well enough alone - they could be grandfathered, at least until this site makes it out of beta.